# Access-Control-Allow-Origin header not found error, when cors is enabled in ASP.NET web api identity

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, cors, google-api-dotnet-client, owin-middleware

I am using Angular 6 @ localhost:4200
& Asp.net Web Api Identity - Individual User Account @ localhost:57310

Now, I enabled cors like this, in my `webapiconfig.cs` file :-

```
EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

It worked fine, But, now when I need to add google+ login authenticaton in my website, it started showing this error again.

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

So, to solve it, I add following code in `<system.webServer>` in `web.config` file.

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*"/>
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

And new error was =>

```
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

If I replace `"*"` by `http://localhost:4200` in any one the cors enabling techniques provided above. The error changes accordingly, like =>

```
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, http://localhost:4200', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

OR

```
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:4200, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

If I remove any one of them, the error revert back to =>

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

**Angular Information**

My Angular code is `this.http.get("http://localhost:57310/api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=Google&response_type=token&client_id=self&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Flogin&state=tTs32zmKbLSJXZP5O46h-GC29j2yrt3TFYYtcG3VY9o1").subscribe(data=>console.log(data));`

If I request this link on browser, it works fine, but not from angular call.
**Web API Information**

My WebAPI `AppilicationOAuthProvider.cs` file method to redirect is:=>

```
public override Task ValidateClientRedirectUri(OAuthValidateClientRedirectUriContext context)
    {
        //context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
        if (context.ClientId == _publicClientId)
        {
            Uri expectedRootUri = new Uri("http://localhost:4200/login");


            if (expectedRootUri.AbsoluteUri == context.RedirectUri)
            {
                context.Validated();
            }
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
```

**Google Developer Account Information**

My Authorized JavaScript Origin Link
`http://localhost:4200`

My Authorized redirect URIs
`http://localhost:57310/signin-google`

Comment: Is it possible for you to call the API from Post Man?

Comment: I think you should focus on the error message: `... has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.`. on the browser, it often call a Pre-flight request (OPTION request) before calling the actual request.

Comment: This's more like a question about IIS configuration, cannot help, sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174162/discussion-between-abhishek-jaiswal-and-envil).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only problem in the code is in Angular Information section. While google authentication, I am issuing a get request but that was wrong. Correct method is =>

```
window.location.href = "http://localhost:57310/api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=Google&response_type=token&client_id=self&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Flogin&state=tTs32zmKbLSJXZP5O46h-GC29j2yrt3TFYYtcG3VY9o1";
```

instead of

```
this.http.get("http://localhost:57310/api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=Google&response_type=token&client_id=self&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Flogin&state=tTs32zmKbLSJXZP5O46h-GC29j2yrt3TFYYtcG3VY9o1").subscribe(data=>console.log(data));
```